# OAuth access token could not be extracted from Mule Message

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, mule, mule-component

I am trying to implement Oauth2 in Mule Connector, for which i am using default methods of Mule Devkit connector platform. But After authenticating i can not user Token due to following error. 
Please help. Included stack trace will help.

```
   Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OAuth access token could not be extracted from: {
  "access_token" : "ya29.GlzxA5CJ8FcIay3YXE7sG2spkYYfkcTei6NW_gunsIPW2kSYJToKh1oOyUwkRoy-p-iuGIwLsi5gKvzhZQPMY9wjPkdxR6YJYVswtR3K3iGXlidqbp1_LAQoEHoX0w",
  "expires_in" : 3599,
  "token_type" : "Bearer"
}
    at org.mule.security.oauth.util.DefaultOAuthResponseParser.extractAccessCode(DefaultOAuthResponseParser.java:36)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.BaseOAuth2Manager.fetchAndExtract(BaseOAuth2Manager.java:586)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.BaseOAuth2Manager.fetchAccessToken(BaseOAuth2Manager.java:432)
    at org.mule.modules.drivecon2.adapters.DriveCon2ConnectorOAuth2Adapter.fetchAccessToken(DriveCon2ConnectorOAuth2Adapter.java:207)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.processor.OAuth2FetchAccessTokenMessageProcessor.doProcess(OAuth2FetchAccessTokenMessageProcessor.java:68)
    at org.mule.devkit.processor.DevkitBasedMessageProcessor.process(DevkitBasedMessageProcessor.java:89)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:129)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:213)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:206)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:205)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:53)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the error.
I was passing Credentials correctly, but with wrong Regex. Change access token URL to below value.(For google Auth responses.)

```
     OAuth2(friendlyName = "OAuth 2.0", authorizationUrl = 
"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    accessTokenUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
     accessTokenRegex = "\"access_token\" : \"([^&]+?)\"", 
    expirationRegex = "\"expires_in\" : ([^&]+?),")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on some oauth2 Mule flows for Google and others please see my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257341/trust-store-for-googleapis-com-certificate-and-oauth-single-signon

To extract the token I'm using a JSON to Object transformer and then #[payload.access_token]

I believe the correct url for token retrieval is  www.googleapis.com:443/oauth2/v4/token which for me does not work I think because of a trust store issue, I also have accounts.google.com:443/o/oauth2/token working but the www.googleapis.com endpoint is needed for subsequent api calls with the returned token at which point the trust issue returns. Interested to hear your thoughts, I would have posted a comment but don't have sufficient points sorry for the abuse